# Define variables in one LESS file

Tags: css, less

I've just started using LESS to simplify my CSS stuff. I want to be able to define the colours in one file, so I can have several colour schemes that I can switch between just by changing which file is being referenced.

I tried something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" href="/css/colours.less" />
<link rel="stylesheet/less" href="/css/styles.less" />
```

But I get "variable not defined" errors in the `styles.less` file.

I can "fix" this by using `import "/css/colours.less"` at the start of `styles.less`, but I have to do this for every single LESS file, and it makes it much, much harder to change what file is being used.

Is there any way to define variables in one file and use them in another? Or any way to auto-import the `colours.less` file at the start of the other files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be compiling your `.less` files into a single `.css` file and including it once on every page (i.e. `styles.less` compiled to `styles.css`). That way the browser doesn't have the overhead of recompiling the CSS every page load. Also the `.css` file can be cached.

Instead of adding:

```
<link href="/css/colours.less" />
<link href="/css/styles.less" />
<link href="/css/forms.less" />
<link href="/css/widgets.less" />
...etc...
```

It should be:

```
<link href="/css/styles.css" />
```

And in `styles.less` you should have:

```
@import 'colours';
@import 'forms';
@import 'widgets';
...etc...
```

Otherwise, if you want to reuse `colours.less` in multiple `.less` stylesheets, you'll need to `@import` them in each stylesheet.

---

For development purposes, I recommend using a single, primary `.less` file that contains only variable declarations and `@import` statements. That way it's easy to find where additional scripts are added. LESS makes it very easy to add or remove stylesheets to keep the code organized.

For example, `style.less` might look something like:

```
// import statements
@import 'core';
@import 'mixins';
@import 'lists';
@import 'buttons';

@import 'forms/form';
@import 'forms/search';
@import 'forms/contact-us';

@import 'modules/module';
@import 'modules/archive';
@import 'modules/events';

// variables
@image-path: '/assets/images/';

@font: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

@black: #000;
@dark-grey: #333;
@grey: #888;
@light-grey: #CCC;
@white: #FFF;
@red: #F00;
```

This structure makes it easy to add a new stylesheet, such as when adding a new module:

```
...
@import 'modules/events';
@import 'modules/foo'; //add another module
...
```

It also makes it very easy to remove styles if they're no longer being used. If the `foo` module was to be removed, it's easy to remove all the `foo` styles simply by removing the `@import 'modules/foo';` statement.

Comment: Okay. I'm currently using browser-side compilation because the site's in development, but when it's ready for opening I can have a "compile" script that automatically adds the relevant import. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: @Kolink, I've updated my answer with some recommendations for how to manage multiple stylesheets.

Comment: Hmm, that gives me an idea. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Chetan, you obviously didn't read this answer. The `.css` extension was **not** a typo.